# How does a NIC work from a kernel's perspective?

Tags: linux, operating-system, driver

Couldn't phrase my question properly so a Google search didn't help me. Can someone explain how a NIC works from a the kernel's perspective. In order for the kernel to talk to the device, you'll need either a driver/kernel module. My questions:

1. I understand that devices are represented as files in Linux. If the driver/module provides user-space APIs to talk to the device, does that mean system-calls such as read/write to the device's file is redundant? I'm not saying one should actually use a system-call to read/write to a device's file, but just for a sake of argument.
2. How does device names such as eth0 fit into all this?
3. Where exactly does tcpdump get it's data? If I run something like:
   `tcpdump -vv -i eth0`
   does tcpdump read from a device file somewhere? It will be too complicated to actually probe the NIC's tx/rx port for the bits that goes in/out of it, so how does tcpdump get it's information?

Any information provided is greatly appreciated. Feel free to provides links to website or books where I can learn more about this.

Answer (score 3):

"If the driver/module provides user-space APIs to talk to the device, does that mean system-calls such as read/write to the device's file is redundant?"

What you are stating here is very similar to the Poll Mode driver provided by the DPDK library.
https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/prog_guide/poll_mode_drv.html
If the driver provides user-space APIs then the read/write, send/recv system calls will become redundant. You must use the APIs provided by the driver to read and write to the NIC devices. 
However if you still want to use the linux system calls such as read/write or send/recv, you could design your application such that after reading the raw data from the driver API, you 'inject' the raw data into the linux kernel, You can achieve this by writing the raw data into a tun/tap device and have your application read the data using linux system calls from the tun/tap device.

"Where exactly does tcpdump get it's data?"

Most packet sniffing applications sniff packets with the help of raw sockets opened at the l2 layer. 
https://www.unix.com/programming/229235-raw-socket-programming-efficient-packet-sniffer.html

Found a post related to tcpdump that gives a more detailed explaination:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23060/what-level-of-the-network-stack-does-tcpdump-get-its-info-from